# Extract substring after the final dot

Tags: r, regex

I want to implement a regex to extract the substring after the final dot.
For example,

```
a = c("a.b.c.d", "e.b.e", "c", "f.d.e", "a.e.b.g.z")
gsub(".*(\\..*)$", "\\1", a)
```

The code returns

```
".d" ".e" "c"  ".e" ".z"
```

How do I modify the code to get

```
"d" "e" ""  "e" "z"
```

That is to say, if the string contains dot, it will remove the last part without the dot; if the string doesn't contain dot, it will return "".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to do this using `sub` without capture groups.  We can try replacing all content up to and including the final dot with empty string.

```
a = c("a.b.c.d", "e.b.e", "c", "f.d.e", "a.e.b.g.z")
sub(".*\\.", "", a)

[1] "d" "e" "c" "e" "z"
```

If you want to return empty string should the input have no dot, then we can use `ifelse` with `grepl`:

```
input <- "Hello World!"
output <- ifelse(grepl("\\.", input), sub(".*\\.", "", input), "")
```

The reason for the verbose above code is that `sub` by default just returns the original string should no match be found.  But, in your case, you want a different behavior.

Comment: Thanks! One more question, for those strings without dots, how to return null string? Say if you have "c" just return "" instead of "c".

Comment: @SaltyGoldFish We can use `grepl` for this case.

Answer (score 2):

You need `.` outside the capture group as you don't need it

```
sub(".*\\.(.*)", "\\1", a)
#[1] "d" "e" "c" "e" "z"
```

This will capture everything after the last dot.

For strings where we have no dots, we could check for it using `grepl` and then extract

```
ifelse(grepl("\\.", a), sub(".*\\.(.*)", "\\1", a), "")
#[1] "d" "e" ""  "e" "z"
```

Comment: Thanks! For those strings without dots, how to return null string? Like if you have "c" just return "" instead of "c".